# Issue Pre-populating form in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to get the user profile name to populate the form field 'user' from AgendaForm but what I get "'user': None".
And, in views, in the following prints:

```py
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            print(initial_data)
```

I get:

```py
{'user': None, 'date': datetime.date(2021, 9, 24), 'time': datetime.time(4, 0), 'comment': 'some comment', 'mode': 'ONLINE'}
{'user': <Profile: Jhon Doe>}
```

## views.py

```py
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['user'])
def agenda(request):
    user = request.user.profile
    initial_data = {
        'user': user
    }
 
    form = AgendaForm(initial=initial_data)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AgendaForm(request.POST, initial=initial_data)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()

            print(form.cleaned_data)
            print(initial_data)

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'agenda.html', context)
```

## agenda.models.py

```py
class Agenda(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default="1900-01-11")
      ...

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.user)
```

## main.models.py

```py
#(The OneToOneField 'User' comes from the UserCreationForm Django function)
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
       ...

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Comment: Did `request.POST` have the `user` passed?

Comment: Isn't it passing with the initial dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects you pass in `initial` is only used for displaying purposes to show some initial values, and not as fallback/default values. So if there is no `user` data found in `request.POST`, it will default to `None`.

From the [**`docs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values):

> These values are only displayed for unbound forms, and they’re not used as fallback values if a particular value isn’t provided.
> This means if the post data does not have user, it will default to `None`.

If you want to set the `agenda`'s user FK to the profile of the current user, you can do:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AgendaForm(request.POST, initial=initial_data)
        if form.is_valid():
            agenda = form.save(commit=False)
            agenda.user = request.user.profile
            agenda.save()
```